# CakePHP resize image served from CakeResponse with Timthumb

Tags: php, image, cakephp, resize, timthumb

I have a view that displays an image from `CakeResponse::file`.  I'm using the Media plugin to initially upload the image that saves the basename to the database which works fine, however I'm blocking access to the media directory with .htaccess so I need to serve the image with a response. I'm using the Html helper to print the img tag.

**Images/view.ctp**:

```
echo $this->Html->image(FULL_BASE_URL.'/Images/imgView/'.$image['Image']['basename']);
```

`Images` is my controller and `imgView` is the action that sends the response:

**ImagesController.php**:

```
public function imgView($file) {
    $this->response->file(WWW_ROOT.'media/transfer/img/'.$file);
    return $this->response;
}
```

This works great, however what i'd like to do is resize the image sent from `CakeResponse::file` dynamically using Timthumb but I haven't had any luck so far, this is what i've tried with timthumb.php in the root of `/app/webroot`.

**Images/view.ctp**:

```
echo $this->Html->image('/timthumb.php?src='.FULL_BASE_URL. '/Images/imgView/'.$image['Image']['basename'].'&amp;h=250&amp;w=250');
```

This just returns an invalid image error, any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried to save the scaled image and open it in a **text-editor**? The generated images probably contains an error message generated by PHP. By opening the file in a text-editor, you'll be able to see that error.

Comment: Hey thaJeztah, I'm getting "The requested URL /timthumb.php was not found on this server."  However I have it within the webroot so I'm not sure what the problem is.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the timthump script, but watching your code, it seems that that script will try to fetch the *original* image via a http-request (which is blocked by your .htaccess), and therefore may throw a 404 error?

Comment: It seems like your correct, I tried moving the timthumb portion to the imgView action and got a "image not readable" error instead.  Any suggestions on resizing images served with CakeResponse?

Comment: Also, please consider to perform the resizing within CakePHP itself, that way you don't have to expose the full path to the original image. Additionally, passing the dimensions as an argument is potentionally **dangerous**, for example, test what happens if somebody changes it to `&h=100000&w=100000`. If the script does not check on max. dimensions, this **will** bring your server down or cause memory-limit errors.

Comment: Either implement the image-scaling yourself, or search for existing plugins/implementations for CakePHP. A quick search on Google gave me this one; https://github.com/martinbean/cakephp-thumbnail-plugin. This one also seems to *store* the scaled images on disk, which is advisable anyway as image-scaling may be quite an intensive process, depending of course on the dimensions of the original image

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [TimthumbPlugin](https://github.com/vishal-logiciel/TimthumbPlugin) for CakePHP. It wraps the timthumb library and provides an easy to use helper for that.